# Why I get an error in ODBC Excel running a file .exe?

Tags: excel, odbc, driver

I'm running a file .exe, and appears a message that said:"Error creating file", and Error in the connection to OBDC Excel driver.

I configured my DNS with a 32bits OBDC driver, but, the problem persists.

I'd really appreciate your support.

Thanks.

I configured my DNS with a 32bits OBDC driver, but, the problem persists.